# VBscript XLS-to-CSV with minor transform

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a system that **only** outputs reports in Excel 97-2003, and a second system (for the user to look at) that **only** accepts these reports in CSV format.  The reports manager was previously opening each of the fifteen XLS reports, find/replacing all the commas with semicolons, saving as CSV, and renaming each file to the specific name that the second system requires.  I heard of his plight and wanted to try my hand at automating the process, so my hamfisted attempt - after about a day of combing through SO and various other sites - follows.

It does work as intended, but I feel like I'm missing some obvious improvement.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFS, objFolder, colFiles, re, objFile, intConvert, userContinue, objXL, objBook, objSheet, strBase

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(".\")
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

Set re = New RegExp
re.Global     = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Pattern    = "\.xls$"

intConvert = 0
For Each objFile in colFiles
  If re.test(objFile.Name) Then
    intConvert = intConvert + 1
  End If
Next

If intConvert = 0 then
  MsgBox "ChangeFile found no files to convert where it was opened." & vbNewLine & "Exiting process."
Else
  userContinue = MsgBox ("ChangeFile found " & intConvert & " files to convert where it was opened." & vbNewLine & _
    "Continue conversion process?", vbYesNo, "Continue Conversion")
  If userContinue = vbYes Then
    'MsgBox "Conversion beginning."
    Set objXL = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objXL.Visible = False
    For Each objFile in colFiles
      If re.test(objFile.Name) Then
        Set objBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
        Set objSheet = objBook.Worksheets(1)
        objSheet.Cells.Replace ",", ";"

        objBook.SaveAs Replace(objFile.Path, ".xls", ".csv"), 6
        objBook.Close True

        strBase = objFS.GetBaseName(objFile)
        Select Case strBase
          Case "[REDACTEDXLS1]"
            objFS.MoveFile strBase & ".csv", "[REDACTEDCSV1].csv"
          Case "[REDACTEDXLS2]"
            objFS.MoveFile strBase & ".csv", "[REDACTEDCSV2].csv"
          Case Else
            MsgBox strBase & " was not renamed - no match found"
        End Select
      End If
    Next
    objXL.Quit
    Set objSheet = nothing
    Set objBook = nothing
    Set objXL = nothing
    Set objFS = nothing
    MsgBox "If you see this message, conversion was completed successfully."
  End If
End If
```

Never mind the REDACTEDs.  My bosses can get a little leery of putting info out there sometimes.  There are only two specific cases listed thus far since I don't have the full list of requirements, which should get to me some time next week.  (Also they are sadly all non-uniform names on both sides of the transform, so there’s no iteration that can be done.)

Possibly more appropriate for SO: I’ve also been advised that repeatedly opening/closing Excel like this can create phantom copies of Excel in memory, but testing with Windows 7 and Excel 2013 (which is what the report manager would be using) I see the second Excel process being created (when I'm already running one) and then removed at the end, so all appears to be well.  Is this something more applicable to an earlier iteration that Office 2013 fixes, or am I justified in worrying about it still?

Comment: Re phantom copies. That is invariably a result of poor error handling. Something goes boom, there's no error handler to kill the Excel process and "bam"! You've got 39 hidden instances of Excel running. Your code suffers from this btw.

Comment: @RubberDuck Thank you!  That makes a lot of sense; so if anything killed the script during the last For loop, it'd leave an invisible Excel hanging around, if I'm parsing you right.  But if that's caused by the script stopping, then how can I use the script to close Excel if the script has already halted?  One of my other associates mentioned having a separate process to hunt and kill any open Excel processes, but that's not very user-friendly if my user is working on something in Excel already.

Comment: NO! Don't go killing processes you don't know you own! Slap your co-worker! Lol. Just look into error handling in VBScript. I bet if you looked at [tag:vba] + [tag:error-handling] here on this site, you'd find some good examples.